# Normalized the Array structure into Multiple documents in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Input is Once Document

```
{
  "name": [
    "abc",
    "xyz"
  ],
  "values": [
    "123",
    "100"
  ]
}
```

The explanation I want to Normalize the Array into multiple documents, `abc`, and `xyz` are dynamically coming, these are user define parameters

**Expected Output**

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "name": "abc",
            "values": "123"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "name": "xyz",
            "values": "100"
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Can there be more values in `name` and `values` array? Can they mismatch in size?

Comment: No, they cannot mismatch the size, the Array length of the `values` and `name` should be the same.

Comment: And what about the count always two?

Comment: the array count can be more, but the count should be the match of both arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use [$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/), like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              inputs: [
                "$name",
                "$values"
              ]
            }
          },
          as: "zipped",
          in: {
            name: {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$zipped",
                0
              ]
            },
            values: {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$$zipped",
                1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        data: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mMYTQ0dNoZj)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "data": {
                $map: {
                    input: { $zip: { inputs: ["$name", "$values"] } },
                    as: "item",
                    in: {
                        name: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$item", 0] },
                        values: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$item", 1] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$data" }
]);
```